# Is it possible to get Slack username as an entity in Watson assistant?

Tags: ibm-watson, slack, watson-conversation

I am thinking about a situation that we use Watson Assistant to pull data from a database using the username of Slack account initiating conversation with it. Is it possible? (Because the user is already authenticated using Slack, we do not need to deal with authentication anymore)

The Slack workspace is connected to Watson using the [Bots](https://slack.com/apps/A0F7YS25R-bots).

Comment: Thank you for your question. However I believe your question is 1) too broad for this forum and 2) should not ask about multiple topics in the same question.

Comment: I just made it less broad, and more specific. Could you please let someone answer this question? It is not too broad and I am not sure how did you find it in that way.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. How do you connect Slack and Watson Assistant? Ar you using Botkit or any other frameworks? Which programming language?

Comment: I just used https://slack.com/apps/A0F7YS25R-bots interface to connect